# React is not picking data from backend nodejs, how to fix that?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

My backend code created using below steps:

```
mkdir backend
cd backend
npm init
npm i express
```

```
//app.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.get('/api/data', (req, res) => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  msg =  'constant message from backend'
  const data = { message: msg };
  res.json(data);
});

app.get('/api/datetime', (req, res) => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const response = {
    date: currentDate.toDateString(),
    time: currentDate.toTimeString(),
  };
  res.json(response);
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Microservice is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

My front end react project created using:

```
npx create-react-app frontend
cd frontend
```

src/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MicroserviceComponent from './MicroserviceComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MicroserviceComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

src/MicroserviceComponent.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const microserviceUrl = 'http://localhost:3001'

const MicroserviceComponent = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [dateTime, setDateTime] = useState({ date: '', time: '' });


useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Fetching data from microservice...');

  // Fetch data from /api/data endpoint
  fetch(`${microserviceUrl}/api/data`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Data from /api/data:', data);
      setMessage(data.message);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));

  // Fetch data from /api/datetime endpoint
  fetch(`${microserviceUrl}/api/datetime`)
 .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Data from /api/datetime:', data);
      setDateTime(data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching datetime:', error));
}, []);

return (
    <div>
      <h1>Microservice Test</h1>
      <p>Message from microservice: {message}</p>
      <p>Date: {dateTime.date}</p>
      <p>Time: {dateTime.time}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MicroserviceComponent;
```

When I ran the backend and request the api, it is working but with frontend react, not getting the backend api output in it.

[react ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7acmB.png)

But react output from webbrowser should show the backend api data

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your code, and it is working fine,
Although, I would suggest some correction in your code.

```
 msg = "constant message from backend";
```

Update this code with const i.e.

```
const  msg = "constant message from backend";
```

As it is an error.

Replace your MicroserviceComponent.js file with :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

const microserviceUrl = "http://localhost:3001";

const MicroserviceComponent = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [dateTime, setDateTime] = useState({ date: "", time: "" });

  const fetchRecords = useCallback(() => {
    Promise.allSettled([
      // Fetch data from /api/data endpoint
      fetch(`${microserviceUrl}/api/data`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("Data from /api/data:", data);
          setMessage(data.message);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching data:", error)),

      // Fetch data from /api/datetime endpoint
      fetch(`${microserviceUrl}/api/datetime`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("Data from /api/datetime:", data);
          setDateTime(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching datetime:", error)),
    ]);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Fetching data from microservice...");
    fetchRecords();
  }, [fetchRecords]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Microservice Test</h1>
      <p>Message from microservice: {message}</p>
      <p>Date: {dateTime.date}</p>
      <p>Time: {dateTime.time}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MicroserviceComponent;
```

Here is the output of your code result :

[image]

As you have stated, It is not working at your end, Can you check your console of the browser as well as the node server?

Probably, you have not started the server.

Can you confirm if your server is up and running? Let me know in the comment.